# Added JAR File in Library - buy cannot use

Tags: netbeans-8

I added a JAR file into the Netbeand (v8) library and added the jar to the compile and file tabs. When I add the import clause, Netbeans is telling me that the library is incorrect. After reading everything I can on what is supposed to be easy, this is getting very frustrating for this newbie. Am I missing an essential step before I can use this library?[image: NetBeans Library and project results]

Answer (score 0):

Answered by fixing my own typo. Fixed and works.